# Keras progress validation accuracy not showing correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

currently i'm training my model using the following *model.fit*

```
history = finetune_model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, workers=1, 
                                         steps_per_epoch=num_train_images // batch_size,
                                validation_data=(x_val, y_val_))
```

And also i'm using the **docker image** from dockerhub `tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.0-gpu-py3-jupyter`

Here is the current showing:

```
Epoch 38/40
61/62 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4109 - acc: 0.9536Epoch 1/40
420/62 [===========================================================================================================================================================================================================] - 2s 4ms/sample - loss: 0.6136 - acc: 0.7190
```

However in Colaboratory, the output is this:

```
Epoch 38/40
62/62 [==============================] - 13s 212ms/step - loss: 0.4069 - acc: 0.8997 - val_loss: 0.7886 - val_acc: 0.752
```

Comment: the validation results are displayed only at the end of epoch

Comment: sure, how can i fix it? i want same as colab output?